# How to show objects in a table in Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

I'm trying to add some objects with the input field, but they don't show up on the website. I can find them in the admin page, but not in the table, where i want them. How can i fix it?

Here is my code:

models.py

```
class Kommentar(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} {self.comment}"
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET:
        q = request.GET['q']
        # literatur = Literatur.objects.filter(name__icontains=q)
        multiple_q = Q(Q(name__icontains=q) | Q(autor__icontains=q) | Q(jahr__icontains=q) | Q(auflage__icontains=q) | Q(verlag__icontains=q) | Q(ort__icontains=q) | Q(isbn__icontains=q))
        literatur = Literatur.objects.filter(multiple_q)
    else:
        literatur = Literatur.objects.all()
    return render(request, "literatur/index.html", {"literatur":literatur})


def commentAction(request):
    user = request.POST["user"]
    comment = request.POST["comment"]

    print(user, comment)

    Kommentar.objects.create(user=user,
                        comment = comment)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('literatur:index'))
```

urls.py

```
app_name = "literatur"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:literatur_id>/', views.detail, name="detail"),
    path('new', views.new, name="new"),
    path('deleteAction/<int:i>/', views.deleteAction, name="deleteAction"),
    path('commentAction', views.commentAction, name="commentAction"),
]
```

index.html

```
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark"> 
  <tr><th scope="col">Username</th><th scope="col">Kommentar</th></tr>
  {% for i in kommentar %}
  <tr>
  <td>{{i.user}}</a></td>
  <td>{{i.comment}}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: You use a redirect response, not a template render response. The problem probably lives in your index view function, which is not included in your question.

Comment: I now added my index view function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside index view function, you make a query to literatur, and pass that to render function to render html template. However the index.html does not care about literatur.

Make a query to Kommentar and pass the queryset to render function

```
def index(request):
   … # Your view logic
   kommentar = Kommentar.objects.all()
   return render(request, ‘literatur/index.html’, {‘literatur’: literatur, ‘kommentur’: kommentur})
```

P.S.

1. The literatur queryset is not used in the index.html template. You may want to just remove this part of view logic, or modify index.html to make use of the queryset;
2. You may want to add trailing slash to ‘new’ and ‘commentAction’ url path in your urls.py